# Recursive subtract

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm trying to write recursive function for subtracting number.

My starting number is 33 and I want to recursive subtract this number by X. X can be any number but for this purpose let it be 1, so the result should be like:

33
32
31
30
29
....

33 - 1 = 32 - 1 = 31 - 1 = 30 - 1 = 29...

Recursive function should return subtracted values to main function.

so far i've done this:

```
void Main()
{
   double x = 1.0;
   for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
   {
        double res = calc(33, x);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}

 static double calc(double val, double roc)
 {
      double c = 0;

      c = val + roc;

      return c;             
  }
```

The loop is each time calling function and send number 33 but and result is always the same. How to return value from calc() method and use this value for the next subtraction?

Comment: Recursive subtractions would be `int sub(int a, int b) => b == 0 ? a : b > 0 ? sub(a-1, b-1) : sub(a+1, b+1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand what you are trying to do here, and your call is not recursive. A recursive call is when a method calls itself.  To answer your question regarding how to use your calculated value in the next iteration, you would do the following.

```
void Main()
{
   double x = 1.0;
   double res = 33
   for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
   {
        res = calc(res, x);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}

 static double calc(double val, double roc)
 {
      double c = 0;

      c = val + roc;

      return c;             
  }
```

Comment: I just started with recursions but seems I put things in totally wrong way. So this what I've done is not recursion...

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned recursion, here is the same logic you have using a recursive method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = calc(33, 1, 10);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static double calc(double startingValue, double valueToSubtract, int numberOfTimes)
{
    if (numberOfTimes == 0)
        return startingValue;
    return calc(startingValue - valueToSubtract, valueToSubtract, numberOfTimes - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve what you sad above using recursion then you can do like this,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double x = 1.0;
        double res = 33;
        calc(res, x);
    }

    static void calc(double val, double roc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(val);
        if (val == 1)
            return;
        val = val - roc;
        calc(val, roc);
    }
}
```